# Como criar objetos distintos a partir de um loop?

Tags: python, loop, python-2.7

```
class linha ():
    def __init__ (self, texto):
        self.texto = texto
def criador ():
    for i in range(5):
        a = raw_input ('escreva: ')
        global objetoi
        objetoi = linha (a)
```

Como faço para que a função `criador` gere um objeto diferente à cada interação no loop `for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque dentro de uma lista:

```
class linha ():
    def __init__ (self, texto):
        self.texto = texto
def criador ():
    lista = []
    for i in range(5):
        a = raw_input ('escreva: ')
        lista.append(linha(a))
```